# Update multiple row in on submit

Tags: php, sql

I want to update table rows in one submit. But i don't know how to do it.

**This is my code**

```
<form  method="POST" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <div class="col-md-7" style="margin-left:370px; height:auto;">
    <h3>Service-Level-Agreement</h3>
    <?php

        $query = "select * from tblsla";
        $request = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());?>
        <table class="table table-hover" style="width:auto;">
        <tr>    
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Easy</th>
                <th>Moderate</th>
                <th>Difficult</th>
                <th></th>
                </tr>
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($request)){
        ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>

                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px;" name="easySla"/></td>   
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px;" name="modSla"/></td>    
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px;" name="difSla"/></td>    
                    <td>Days</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php
        }

?>  
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Edit SLA" class="btn btn-success"/>
    </div>

        <input type="hidden"  name="idUser" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" />
    </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $easy = $_POST["easySla"];
$mod = $_POST["modSla"];
$diff = $_POST["diffSla"];


if(is_int($easy) AND is_int($mod) AND is_int($diff)){
    echo " Invalid Inputs ";
    }
else
  {
  $sql = "UPDATE tblsla SET  easySLA = '$easy', modSLA = '$mod', difSLA = '$diff' WHERE id = '$id'";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$success = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
}
if ($success == TRUE){
    ?>
        <script>
            alert('You have successfully update account.');
        </script>

    <?php
}
  }

?>
```

This is the image for what i want to happen[image: This is what im trying to do.]

**Thank you so much!**

Comment: you have severals input with same name. you need to use array as input name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have severals input with same name.
use array in your input name

Try something like this:

```
 <form  method="POST" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
        <div class="col-md-7" style="margin-left:370px; height:auto;">
            <h3>Service-Level-Agreement</h3>
            <?php

            $query = "select * from tblsla";
            $request = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());?>
            <table class="table table-hover" style="width:auto;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Easy</th>
                    <th>Moderate</th>
                    <th>Difficult</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($request)){
                    ?>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>

                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px;" name="easySla[]"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px;" name="modSla[]"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px;" name="difSla[]"/></td>
 <td>  <input type="hidden"  name="idUser[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" /></td>
                        <td>Days</td>

                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                <?php
                }

                ?>
            </table>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Edit SLA" class="btn btn-success"/>
        </div>


    </form>
```

In your php you have an array with all rows. You need loop through this array and insert data in your database.

Try like this:

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$count = count($_POST['easySla']); //get total number of array element
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { // loop through array and assign values in variable and insert itin database
    $easy = $_POST['easySla'][$i];
    $mod = $_POST["modSla"][$i];
    $diff =$_POST["difSla"][$i];
    $id = $_POST["idUser"][$i];
    if (is_numeric($easy) && is_numeric($mod) && is_numeric($diff)) {

        $sql = "UPDATE tblsla SET  easySLA = '$easy', modSLA = '$mod', difSLA = '$diff' WHERE id = '$id'";
        $success = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        if ($success == false) {
            break;
        }
    } else {

        echo " <script>
               alert('invalid input not a number.');
               </script>";
        header("location: yourfile_name.php");
    }
}
if ($success) {
    echo " <script>
      alert('You have successfully update account.');
    </script>";
    header("location: yourfile_name.php");
} else {
    echo " <script>
    alert('You have errors.');
     </script>";
    header("location: yourfile_name.php");
}
```

}

Let me know if you have any questions ..

Comment: I am updating my answer. give me one moment

Comment: @Ralfh: try updated  answer

Comment: After filling up and submitting, the table is not updating. But it gives me the successful message but loops till 7 times.

Comment: what you have in your `$id` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45968/discussion-between-awlad-liton-and-ralfh)

Comment: im still in or chatbox

Comment: Im still in out chatbox Awlad Liton

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop to update all rows in a table with different data or same data...

**If you have different data for all rows take that data in an array and start looping with that array length , In that loop write a query to update data in each row.**

Ex: $array=[[row1][row2][row3]]
    for loop of length $array{
      $query="update table set row1='data of row1'",row2='data of row2'... "`enter code here`
    }

Comment: Can you give me an example?